# Center text below button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How can I center text below a button inside a column within a row?
I want to align the text within `<small>` tag exactly in the center below the button:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 vcenter">
                   <h2>Talk to us about your <span class="u">next</span> building project. </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-quote">Get A Free Quote</button>
                    <small>We will contact you within 24 hours.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTqPS.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elkNX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the button in the center?
If so, you just have to give `Text-align: center` to your `<small>` div.

Can you give a picture of the behavior you want ?

Edit : If even so, the text isn't in the center, you may want to add either or both : `display: block` and/or `width: 100%` to `<small>`

Comment: I just attached the image. i want the text below the button to be centered

Comment: Is the button centered within its column ? Is it taking the whole space in the colomn ?
If your answer to both question is Yes, try the things i explained in my answer and tell me if it works. I guess the `small` div is not large enough for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
small {
   display: block; 
   text-align: center; 
}
```

This turns to block and it centers the inner text.

Sorry for the brevity, I'm in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how is the button related to the column its in?
Is it centered? Is it full width?

If the answer is yes to one of this, you could go with:

```
small {
   display: block; 
   text-align: center; 
}
```

If not, you need to wrap the button and the small in another container.

http://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/dXOyGW

Comment: This is perfect. But instead I used the `text-center` bootstrap class.

Comment: Good point, but the class does not make the container an inline block.
Therefore the button will be centered in its container as well. Just wanted to show all options here.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is

```
small{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```